# Подскажите как правильно написать SELECT

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Здравствуйте, подскажите как правильно записать цикл для создания массива значений `meta_value` после выборки. Пытаюсь так:

```
$team_id = (int)$slug;
$team_id=(string)preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $team_id);
global $wpdb;
$newtable = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_id FROM wp_cfs_values where post_id='". $team_id ."'" );

$res=json_encode($newtable);
var_dump($res);
$wpdb->close();
foreach($res as $item)
{

    $newres=[];
    $newtable = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_id='". $item['meta_id'] ."'" );
    $newtable['meta_value']=$newres['meta_value'];

}

$res=json_encode($newres);


return var_dump($res);
```

}

вардамп `$res`:

```
string(267) "[{"meta_id":"1630"},{"meta_id":"1631"},{"meta_id":"1632"},{"meta_id":"1633"},{"meta_id":"1634"},{"meta_id":"1635"},{"meta_id":"1636"},{"meta_id":"1637"},{"meta_id":"1638"},{"meta_id":"1639"},{"meta_id":"1640"},{"meta_id":"1641"},{"meta_id":"1642"},{"meta_id":"1643"}]" string(4) "null" 0
```

Вангую что не очень хорошо пытаюсь в цикле делать запросы по ключам, но как иначе? В общем подскажите куда копать.

Comment: В цикле можно собрать массив значений `meta_id`, а потом сделать запрос с WHERE *** IN ***

Comment: `SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_id IN(SELECT meta_id FROM wp_cfs_values where post_id=XXX)`  или то же самое с JOIN.Рекомендую потратить пару часов и изучить базовый SQL, в жизни пригодится

Comment: Если Вы хотите получить список всех значений meta поста можно использовать функцию get_post_meta() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов спасибо, это то что нужно, тогда все селекты бессмысленны) только начал изучать wordpress.

Comment: @Mike за 2 года первый раз пригодился, вот и подзабыл чутка, where in вообще не использовал ни разу, только join